# How can a cursor tell that the ContentProvider has not been updated?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I'm making an app that uses a Content Provider to store data from an API to an SQLite database, and a cursor that pulls from the Content Provider to bring the data to the UI. The problem is, when the WiFi or Mobile Network is turned off on the phone, nothing loads, but the cursor still brings the data that was LAST pulled from the API to the UI, making the data outdated and hence incorrect. I tried making a static Boolean in the API sync algorithm that is false when an IOException is caught, to try and signal the adapter not to load the info, but it still does.

How can I signal to the cursor itself, or any other component in my app, that the Content Provider has not been updated, so the cursor shouldn't load the data onto the UI? My code is mostly full of stuff specific to my app, so I thought it wouldn't be useful to post any of it, but I will gladly post some of my code if it help anyone answer the question.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "I'm making an app that uses a Content Provider to store data from an API to an SQLite database" -- I would not recommend that approach. IMHO, a `ContentProvider` should be working purely off of a local data store. Syncing that local data store with a remote data store is the job of something else (e.g., service with `AlarmManager`, `JobScheduler`, `SyncAdapter`).

Comment: Is there no way to do what I want to do with a Content Provider? I've already made the entire app with it, and I don't want to break anything, as I'm close to production. I'll definitely consider doing it your way in the next version, but for now, could I do what I want to do with a Content Provider?

Comment: "Is there no way to do what I want to do with a Content Provider?" -- only via hacks like your static `boolean`. I cannot say why that did not work for you. You could also return an empty `Cursor`, and put smarts in your adapter to handle that empty `Cursor` with appropriate messages for the user.

Comment: I see. Well, I will go ahead and try and implement it in the away that you suggested earlier. Would an AsyncTask be a good way to pull from an API instead of a ContentProvider or SyncAdapter?

Comment: "Would an AsyncTask be a good way to pull from an API instead of a ContentProvider or SyncAdapter?" -- I do not know enough about your app to answer that. Usually, an `AsyncTask` is for lightweight background work driven by a UI, where the work will happen fairly quickly (sub-second).

Comment: i am assuming you are using your Cursor with a `CursorLoader`, right? if so make a custom `CursorLoader` class and override `loadInBackground` / `deliverResult`

Comment: Yes, I'm using a CursorLoader. What would I have to override to make it work? How could I check to see that the ContentProvider is still the same? I don't mean to keep asking you, but I'm completely stumped.

Comment: @CommonsWare Alright, I'll try an AsyncTask and see how long it takes to execute. Else, I'll use on of your suggestions to get the data.

Comment: just "ask" your provider if anything changed or not, see `ContentResolver` docs

Comment: @pskink I'll look into that as well. Thank you!